# Where Clause Case Statement

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

How can I have a where clause be based on a variable:

If I have a variable `@PrintNum` and it has a number I want a different where clause, but it not it is different. See below: Is this possible?

```
Where PrintNum = @PrintNum
Else
Where InvNum = @InvNum,
```

etc....

Comment: It's not very clear what your'e asking. Please [edit] your question to include sample data as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

`where PrintNum = @PrintNum or InvNum = @InvNum`

You can chain together as many things in a where clause as you like using either `or` or `and` statements

Comment: Ok, but will that still with what I need. If there is a PrintNum that will trump everything, if not the where clause is a lot longer then I posted. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, I don't understand what you're asking.